# Do I need to root ( unlock boot loader) to flash Factory image for Nexus 5

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-5

Do I need to unlock boot loader to flash official factory image of Android L Preview ? And will it void warranty? Is it rooting the phone ? I have never rooted phone before and I don't wish to do so. Please provide useful link on how to flash such images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to **unlock the bootloader** to flash the factory image.

Yes it will void your warranty but you can lock your bootloader again and reset the tamper flag to get the warranty back

No unlocking bootloader is not rooting.

Here is the useful link.

1. [Unlocking bootloader](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/guide-nexus-5-how-to-unlock-bootloader-t2507905)
2. [Flashing factory image](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/tutorial-how-to-flash-factory-image-t2513701)

Comment: One more question.. Can I roll back to Android 4.4.4 from Android L preview? Just in case its too buggy.. And if yes what is the process to do so..

Comment: @abhi yes you can. You can just flash 4.4.4 or other factory image just like the L preview. Between the preview version is laggy

Comment: thanks a lot Sammer..can I use Nexus Root Tool to unlock> Flash L> Relock ?

Comment: @abhi I never tried Wugfresh tool. I heard few device got into bootloop when using rootkits, so always go with manually typing the command.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the USA it should not void your warranty as it is regulated by law and the manufacturer must prove you actively damaged your phone in the the process (which would be at least funny if you are putting a Google Android Image on a Nexus phone and following the steps Google itself published, for example).

The Magnuson-Moss Warranty Act states on [Title 15 of US Code, Chapter 15 (Consumer Product Warranties), Section 2304 (c)](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/2304) that the manufacturer must prove the damage inflicted by the user to void the warranty, as explained  on this [video](http://youtu.be/9YcIHaajda8?t=1m12s).

In the European Union there is an equivalent ruling on [EU Directive 1999/44/CE](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:31999L0044%3aen%3aHTML)